# Ampersands in text fields are screwing around with display of field data

Tags: php, mysql, escaping, ampersand

I have a customer mangement system that I have programmed in php and mysql. A company uses it to log their customer details for marketing and orders. There are various fields on my form, one of them being Business Name.

The fields are imported into an emailer to send to the customers quotes etc. The field contents are pulled in from the database and stored in various strings. Business name for example is stored in `$name`.

The problem I have found is if the business enters a business name such as `Joe Blogs & Sons` what ends being imported into the email system is `Joe Blogs` and that is it, anything after the  ampersand is cut off, including the ampersand. If they use `Joe Blogs and Sons` this works fine and when the email goes out it says `Dear, Joe Blogs and Sons` , but if someone enters `&` it just ends up as `Dear, Joe Blogs`.

Would I be correct in saying something like s`tr_replace` or `preg_replace` is the way to go with this or a way to escape the `&`'s ? .

Comment: Have you checked if the names are correctly stored in the database? If they are, maybe you should just apply the function `htmlentities()` to the variables before printing/echoing them into the e-mail.

Comment: Too little information. There are many steps on the way, where exactly does the text go missing?

Comment: It goes missing whenever it is pulled out of the database and added to a string then echo'd, so if I select from db and put the results in a string then echo the string, the & and everything after it is gone. The name are stored in the database fine, as they pull them back into the fields when edited.

Comment: @IainSimpson: Is it cut in the email as well? Where do you view the string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use either `htmlentities()` or `htmlspecialchars()` to encode special HTML entities for injection into an HTML context.  Please note that these functions *are not sufficient* for any other context.  Example:

**Good:**

```
<p><?php echo htmlspecialchars($foo); ?></p>
```

**Bad:**

```
<a href="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($bar); ?>">Click me!</a>
```

Comment: Hi,I know this be ok for html emails, but will it work work for the plain text email though, what I mean is will it send Dear Smith &amp; Son , or do I have to strip it again before I send it ?.

Comment: @IainSimpson: Plain text is plain text.  You don't need to encode anything for that context.  Just `echo $foo;` or whatever.

Comment: `<a href="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($bar, ENT_QUOTES);?>">Click me!</a>` good!

Comment: @CarlosCampderrós: `$bar = 'javascript: alert(document.cookie);';`  Nope, still bad.

Answer (score 0):

try to convert & into `&amp;`.
there are various php functions for that.choose one that suits you

Comment: Would this be converted on sending of the email, and not of saving the data to the db ?, as if I replace the & with &amp; it would get pulled into the field name if the record was edited, I was just wondering if it was possible to str_replace the & with and on POST.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you mean by "imported into an emailer".

I'd imagine you just need to convert the `&`'s into `&amp;`'s - probably best just to use [htmlentities](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) around each variable (assuming they don't hold HTML that needs parsed) as part of your "string cleaning" process.